# Database transactions, write-ahead logs, and indexes

Tags: sql, database, transactions

A transaction can recover consistency in case of a problem through a write-ahead log. That is the write-ahead log contains the information to fix the entries of rows that were mutated. But what about a B+ tree index? A SQL insert transaction would need to entered into the write-ahead log of course. But what happens to the B+ tree as the insert would mutate the state of the B+ tree. How does a transaction recover the state of the B+ tree. How is the B+ tree implemented in the context of a transaction to maintain consistency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be handled differently by different RDBMS. In the case of oracle the change to the index is divided in two operations: the so called index split and the insert into the index. The index split is only necessary when there is not enough space in the index block. The operation of index splitting is executed as a so called recursive transactions. Index splits are not rolled back, however the insert into the index is.